# MySQL update column value where else update another column value (single query)

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I would like to link these two queries together rather than executing them both at different times.

```
UPDATE `table` SET `column_one` = @value WHERE `column_one_key` = @key LIMIT 1;
```

and also this query;

```
UPDATE `table` SET `column_two` = @value WHERE `column_two_key` = @key LIMIT 1;
```

Something like this but can't seem to get it to work

```
UPDATE `table` (SET `column_one` = @value WHERE `column_one_key` = @key) || (SET `column_two` = @value WHERE `column_two_key` = @key) LIMIT 1;
```

Some additional information

column_one_key and column_two_key are never the same which is why you can use OR.

Comment: The `limit` makes this pretty difficult.  Leave this as two separate queries.

Comment: I would ask why are you using the `LIMIT` ? Can you show some sample data and how it would look like after those commands were executed?

Comment: Just to stop the query after it's updated the value? As there will be no duplicated items in the table. It's basically a table used to link two fields from another table together. However, it has extra data regarding each item that is linked, which is the column which I'm trying to set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need the `limit` (that is, one match per key), you can do:

```
UPDATE `table`
     SET column_one = (CASE WHEN @key = column_one_key THEN @value ELSE column_one END),
         column_two = (CASE WHEN @key = column_two_key THEN @value ELSE column_two END)
    WHERE @key IN (column_one_key, column_two_key);
```

I think two updates are simpler.  And, if you do need the `limit`, then two updates are definitely a simpler approach.

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this:

```
UPDATE `table` SET `column_one` = @value, `column_two` = @value  WHERE `column_one_key` = @key AND `column_two_key` = @key LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: column_one_key and column_two_key are never the same. So this would not work. Using 'or' would also make this not work as would set both values. Should only set column_one if column_one_key is equal and only set column_two if column_two_key is equal